# undefined reference in pure virtual function C++

Tags: c++, class, reference, undefined, pure-virtual

I am having some difficulties with a c++ program that I need to run. The problem itself is not mine and I have to make it compile. The algorithm is pretty huge so for my current error message I will demonstrate a much more simplified version of a code that I produced that gives me the exact same error. Here is the code:

class_1.h (class_1.cpp is empty)

```
class class_1  {
public:
class_1();
virtual ~class_1();
virtual void function() =0;
};
```

class_2.h (class_2.cpp is empty)

```
include"class_1.h";

class class_2 : public class_1{
public:
class_2();
virtual ~class_2();
virtual void function();
};
```

class_2a.h (class_2a.cpp is empty)

```
include"class_2.h";

class class_2a : public flos2{
public:
class_2a();
virtual ~class_2a();
};
```

class_3.h

```
include "class_2a.h"
include "class_1.h" //I tried unsuccesfully without including class_1.h as well

class class_3 {
public:
class_3();
virtual ~class_3();
virtual void function();
private:
class_2a my_class_2a;
};
```

class_3.cpp

```
#include "class_3.h"

class_3::class_3()
:my_class_2a()
    {
    }

class_3::~class_3()
{
 this->function();
}

void flos3::function()
{
my_class_2a.function();
/***Main Body of function***/
}
};
```

The error I am getting is linker error:

```
undefined reference to `class_2::function()'
```

I know that in general the whole algorithm seems to be stupid, but more or less this is the what I was given and I am not allowed to change the structure itself, just to make it working. As you can see in `class_1` function is defined as a pure virtual function, and then is called through the other classes. I really don't know how to make this thing work, so any help would be really appreciated...

Comment: You are not allowed to change class_2.cpp to add an implementation of function ?

Comment: Please make a minimum test case which compiles (and still has the undefined reference)

Comment: Virtual functions of base class or interface should be implemented in its derived class. In class_2.cpp i don't see any implementation of `virtual void function()`

Comment: Is flos* a typo in your code snippet?

Comment: Ι can't add anything in class_2.cpp, in class_2.cpp there is no implementation of function, it doesn't have any body.
As for flos3 I wanted to type class3 instead.

Comment: In what file do you get the error?

Comment: You can't instantiate an object for a class with virtual function. In which class `virtual void function()` implemented ?

Comment: @user3111197 If you can't change the corresponding source file, but the header (which sounds a bit strange for me), then provide an inline implementation for `class_2::function()` there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

class_1.cpp:

```
class_1::~class_1() = default;
```

class_2.cpp:

```
class_2::~class_2() = default;
void class_2::function() {
    // add code here (or not)
}
```

... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting linker error because your function `class_2::function()` does not have implementation. You need to add it, preferably in class_2.cpp file.

```
void class_2::function()
{
    // Implementation goes here
}
```

Similar problem is with all virtual destructors. They need implementations as well.